# Non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx-11

```
void Triangle::createShaders(Renderer& renderer)
{
    ifstream vsfile("triangleVertexShader.cso", ios::binary);
    ifstream psfile("trianglePixelShader.cso", ios::binary);

    vector<char> vsData = { istreambuf_iterator<char>(vsfile), istreambuf_iterator<char>() };
}
```

Im getting the error C2552: 'vsData' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list.

Comment: Enable C++11? `// filler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS2012 does not support C++11 initializer lists, use the standard constructor syntax:

```
vector<char> vsData(istreambuf_iterator<char>(vsfile), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```